# Отправка на печать файла из php

Tags: php, phpword

Использую такой код для формирования чека по шаблону phpWord:

```
require_once '../../PHPWord/PHPWord.php';
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

 foreach ( $_POST['printt'] as $k=>$m) {
 if (!empty($m)) { 
 $mass[$k] = $m; 

$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('chek.docx'); //шаблон
 $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT mu.fullname as fln, mu.address as adr, mp.name as namep, mp.price as pricep FROM   modx_shopkeeper3_orders  mo
left JOIN  modx_shopkeeper3_purchases mp on mp.order_id=mo.id
left join modx_user_attributes mu on mu.id=mo.userid
where mo.id='".$mass[$k]."'");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($sql2);
$document->setValue('user', $row1[0]); // 

 $sql="SELECT mu.fullname as fln, mu.address as adr, mp.name as namep, mp.price as pricep FROM   modx_shopkeeper3_orders  mo
left JOIN  modx_shopkeeper3_purchases mp on mp.order_id=mo.id
left join modx_user_attributes mu on mu.id=mo.userid
where mo.id='".$mass[$k]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$blyudo = '';
$summa = 0;
$i = 1;
while ($parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $blyudo .=$i.".". $parent['namep'].".....".$parent['pricep']."р.<w:br />";
    $i = $i +1;
    $summa = $summa + $parent['pricep'];
}

$document->setValue('blyudo', $blyudo);
$document->setValue('itogo', $summa);
$document->setValue('city', $row1[1]); //фамилия отчество


$filename='Template_full'.$today.'.docx';

header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word" );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename );

//$docume');nt->save( "php://output" );
//exec('lp '.$filename.'.doc
$document->save($filename.'.docx'); //имя заполненного шаблона для сохранения 
 }
 }
```

А как отправить на печать сформированный docx ?

Comment: У метода save раньше вроде были параметры (на вывод, на скачивание, помню буквами регулировалось I,E и еще что-то, но могу ошибаться). Сейчас самое простое это отдать документ в поток и на js вызвать печать.

Comment: я тоже вычитал про js печать, только не могу понять как организовать поток и через js напечатать

Comment: `$document->save( "php://output")` - это вывод в поток, затем ниже вызвать `<script type="text/javascript">window.print();</script>`

Comment: а в пхп как js вызвать? print "<script type="text/javascript">window.print();</script>" ?

Comment: лучше закрыть php тег перед вызовом js

Comment: когда вывожу в поток вот такое вылазит

Warning: rename(): Cannot rename a file across wrapper types in /var/www/vhosts/u0005768.plsk.regruhosting.ru/pd.ulikes.ru/assets/PHPWord/PHPWord/Template.php on line 114

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать как минимум `$document->save($filename.'.docx');`. Вообще так удаленно трудно помогать, с PHPWord сам сталкивался раза 3-4 всего.

Comment: удалил вообще, но все ровно

Comment: я так понял он ругается на код в Template.php

   public function save($strFilename) {
        if(file_exists($strFilename)) {
            unlink($strFilename);
        }
        
        $this->_objZip->addFromString('word/document.xml', $this->_documentXML);
        
        // Close zip file
        if($this->_objZip->close() === false) {
            throw new Exception('Could not close zip file.');
        }
        
        rename($this->_tempFileName, $strFilename);
    }

Comment: Ругается, потому что нет файла, с которым можно работать. Тогда лучше сохранить его, затем поднять и отправить на печать через js

Comment: я не могу разобраться с печатью на js

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63213/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-aslero).